# Get tabledata from webpage into Excel using macro

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I use a Excel sheet to do some calculation, like assessment of incometax returns. I need to pull data from website into Excel sheet. I successfully did it by using VBA step by step

1. Create internet explorer application in VBA
2. Navigate to website url and login
3. Fill a form automatically by a unique id already in my Excel sheet
4. Now submit form and result page has data in table form
5. Now by using `getelementsbyid("tableid")` I copied and pasted data in excel sheet.

My question

1. All tables  don't have id or name
2. There is lot of tables

Now I want to pull data from a table without id which is third table from top. How to do this? I tried hard. I don't want  all tables because rows in these tables always changed so when I copy all tables data.

Comment: Why would you want to create an 'internet explorer application' using vba? Excel already has a `Data --> From Web` option.

Answer (score 0):

Start macro recording, go to Data -> From Web, open the required web page in the import dialog, select the required table, set all import options as needed, and import the data. Then stop recording.

You will get a boiler plate with auto generated macro code, then it will be trivial to fine turn it to your needs.

I did it many times and this is so easy that I haven't stored a snipped to share with you right now.

Update: this is how to import you question from this page

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158928/get-tabledata-from-webpage-into-excel-using-macro/18160278#18160278" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "18160278#18160278"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells ' adjust this setting to your needs
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "1" ' this is the number of the required table on a page
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Because I have to perform login and many other actions to go to required webpage. I know about webquery. It is not that simple. Anyway thanks